# Getting the source URL from an existing Shopify product image in Python

Tags: python, image, api, url, shopify

I'm basically having trouble seeing how a Shopify image url is stored and what I should write to access it. I'm not a python expert, so it could be something simple I'm not seeing.

Shopify has an API that allows app developers to access products, orders, and the like from a shop. I'm able to get a list of all the products of my shop and grab information like the title and price, but I'm having trouble grabbing the image url. Here's some basic code of what's happening and what I need:

```
import shopify

#other code that accesses my shop

products = shopify.Product.find() #Here I grab a list of all the products
for product in products:
    title = product.title
    price = float(product.variants[0].price) #I'm not sure on the price either, but it works for now
    image_urls = create_image_url_list(product.images) # And here's where I want to create the list of strings using product.images

create_image_url_list(product_images):
    image_urls = []
    for image in product_images:
        product_image_url = '' # Somehow get source url from product image here as string
        image_urls.append(product_image_url)
    return image_urls
```

I believe each product has a list of image(s). What I want to be able to do is create a list of image source urls as strings for each product. Looking at the [Shopify API Documentation for Product](http://docs.shopify.com/api/product), I see that the `product.images` attribute looks like this:

```
{ "images" : "[ { "src": "http://example.com/burton.jpg" } ]"}
```

And when I do a pdb.set_trace() on `product.images`, it looks like this (I changed the numbers for privacy):

```
[image(12345678), image(12345678), image(12345678), image(12345678)]
```

When I do a dir() on one of the images, I get this:

```
['_ShopifyResource__get_id', '_ShopifyResource__set_id', '_ShopifyResource__to_xml_element', '__class__', '__cmp__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattr__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__metaclass__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_build_list', '_build_object', '_class_delete', '_class_get', '_class_head', '_class_post', '_class_put', '_collection_path', '_connection', '_custom_method_collection_url', '_custom_method_element_url', '_custom_method_new_element_url', '_element_path', '_find_class_for', '_find_class_for_collection', '_find_every', '_find_one', '_find_single', '_format', '_headers', '_id_from_response', '_initialized', '_instance_delete', '_instance_get', '_instance_head', '_instance_post', '_instance_put', '_load_attributes_from_response', '_password', '_plural', '_prefix', '_prefix_options', '_prefix_parameters', '_prefix_source', '_primary_key', '_query_string', '_singular', '_site', '_split_options', '_threadlocal', '_timeout', '_update', '_user', 'activate_session', 'attach_image', 'attributes', 'clear_session', 'count', 'create', 'delete', 'destroy', 'errors', 'exists', 'find', 'find_first', 'find_one', 'get', 'get_id', 'head', 'id', 'is_new', 'is_valid', 'klass', 'post', 'put', 'reload', 'save', 'set_id', 'to_dict', 'to_xml']
```

EDIT:

With Pawelmhm's help, the resulting code to accessing the source url is:

```
products = shopify.Product.find() #Here I grab a list of all the products
for product in products:
    title = product.title
    price = float(product.variants[0].price)
    image_urls = [getattr(i, 'src') for i in product.images] # Reduced it to list comprehension using solution
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know what you are looking for here, product_images is a "dictionary-like" object with "images" as keys and a list of dictionaries as values. Have you tried something like this?

```
for image in product_images:
     #product_image_url = '' 
     image_urls.append(image["images"])
```

or perhaps?

```
for image in product_images.to_dict():
     image_urls.append(image["images"]["src"])
```

Tell me if it works, and if it doesn't tell me what error are you getting. I'm curious about this. Also what are you getting when you are doing this your way (the way you have in your code publlished here)? I mean without this empty string of course which abolishes everything, but without empty string, what list are you getting?

EDIT: Ah, this should work!

```
for image in product_images: 
     image_urls.append(image["src"])
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! So I tried out all three variations and received the same error for each.
TypeError: 'Image' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
But you got me thinking and looking at the dir() information again, I saw '__getattr__'. I looked up how to use that method and I found that doing getattr(image, 'src') works :) Thank you!

Comment: Is there a way to get the id of the image immediately after you save it? The only way I can think of is to grab the list of images from the product dict and get the last image which should be the last one you added.